# disqus widget copy and paste to my page

Tags: comments, disqus, same-origin-policy

I setup the DISQUS and found some very interesting thing that it is just a small Javascript code which identified site-account by disqus_shortname and/or disqus_identifier.  So if I copy code from any other site which uses disqus then Its work on my web page too by using that site's disqus_shortname and/or disqus_identifier. Disqus will populate my page with comments for that particular thread without checking out If it is legitimate account/page.

Is that fine/expected practice/behavior for a comments system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, default setting is not very secured. Try to set *Trusted Domains in Advanced Settings*.

> You may optionally specify a list of trusted domains (one per line)
>   that are allowed to connect to your Disqus comments embed.
>       Specify one domain per line.
>       The domain will include all subdomains below it, e.g. blog.disqus.com will include that domain, as well as foo.blog.disqus.com and bar.blog.disqus.com.

Update:

`localhost` is always enabled, see comments and @kuldeep.kamboj findings

Comment: This setting not working for me, I setup a domain into list of trusted domains. But disqus still shows comments on my localhost page.

Comment: Then I assume their code is broken and I suggest to submit bug report. Because their software is client-side deployed (from websites perspective) there is no more security checks possible than URL. If it does not work it is major issue because anobody can steal your discussions with copy/paste of seven lines of JS code.

Comment: Actually it is, I am able to show some big news websites comments section on my local page... Wondering if trusted domain feature is working why they do not use it ?

Comment: "If it does not work" - I meant trusted domain check. You shall contact them with bug report. PS disqus is awesome easy to set up. But it looks like this part is buggy.

Comment: After analyze more, It is like feature itself working on domain but not on localhost. If I copied any disqus plugin code to my localhost page it showing comments while on some other domain feature works and widget seems blocked.

Comment: Good point. This behaviour may be intentional because it does not block developers testing their products while keeping normal users safe.

Comment: No, I am assuming, you are right about their intentional localhost gotcha :) So accepting your answer.